# How do I write a jQuery function to swap out a partial in Rails 3?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

Total newb here so please don't assume that I know anything :)

I'm trying to create a page for teams that will allow you to perform a couple of different tasks. What I would like to do is create a link on the page for each task and then swap out the partial in the center of the page so that the user can perform that task.

So, in my show.html.erb page I have a link like this:

```
<a href="#" id="add_team_mate">Add a Team Mate</a>
```

and a div like this:

```
<div id="team_action">
```

In application.js, I have a function like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#add_team_mate").click(function() {
            alert("Hello world!");
            return false;
        });
});
```

which is just a placeholder until I can figure out how to swap out the content in `<div id=team_action">` with an appropriate partial. Any help or pointers to jQuery documentation or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like `jQuery("#team_action").empty().append(<new partial html goes here>);`. you'd get the partial from an ajax rendered view? Sorry I'm not versed in ruby and can't help with that.

EDIT:
Empty() removes all the contents. Append() will add the partial inside the div.

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Thanks James. One issue with Rails is that it's been using Prototype rather than jQuery. With the new version 3 release there is an official supported branch that replaces Prototype with jQuery. I'm leaning towards swapping Prototype with jQuery because, just like your answer, I can find a lot of examples in jQuery and just about none in Prototype.

Comment: Got it working. I added `gem 'jquery-rails'` to my Gemfile. Then `bundle install` and finally `rails generate jquery:install` (N.B. choose yes when it asks you to overwrite rails.js). Bam, I've got jQuery instead of Prototype and the above function works!

Comment: @spinlock I'm sorry to tell you that I know next to nothing about rails ;). Jquery on the other hand, we've started using it at work and I can't understand why I'd ever had used anything else ;)